# dlmalloc's mspace_malloc returns strange addresses

Tags: c, malloc, systems-programming

[I've solved this problem--please see my last comment below.]

In my application, I need to use my own special malloc, based on Doug Lea's dlmalloc:  I map an anonymous file (using mmap), create an mspace out of part of the mapped file, and pass the mspace to mspace_malloc.  I am finding that some of the addresses that mspace_malloc returns are not within the bounds of the mapped file--even though, as far as I can tell, the process can write to and read from the malloc'ed memory just fine.  Why am I encountering this behavior, and what can I do to force mspace_malloc to return an address within the range of the mspace?

```
/* Inside dl_malloc.c */

#define ONLY_MSPACES 1
#define MSPACES 1

void * heap;
off_t heap_length;
mspace ms;

void init(size_t size) {
  heap = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (heap == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("init: mmap");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  heap_length = size;
  ms = create_mspace(heap, size, 0);
  mspace_track_large_chunks(ms, 1);
}

void * my_malloc(size_t bytes) {
  return mspace_malloc(heap, bytes);
}
/************************/


/* In application */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEAP_SIZE 0x10000  // 32 pages
#define ROWS 2
#define COLS 4096

extern void init(void);
extern void * my_malloc(size_t bytes);

extern void * heap;
extern off_t heap_length;

int main(void) {
  init(HEAP_SIZE);
  int ** matrix = (int **)my_malloc(sizeof(int *) * ROWS);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
    matrix[i] = (int *)my_malloc(sizeof(int) * COLS);

  printf("Heap bounds: %lx to %lx\n",
    (off_t)heap, (off_t)heap + heap_length);
  printf("Matrix: %p  ", matrix;
  for (i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
    printf("Matrix[%d]: %p  ", i, matrix[i]");
  printf("\n");

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this program (well, the above is a simplification, but not by much), I see that the address assigned to matrix is within the bounds printed for the heap, but that the two addresses for the two rows are very far *below* the lower bound--more than 0x100000000 below it!  And yet I seem to be able to read and write to the matrix.  This last point I find puzzling and would like to understand, but the more urgent issue is that I need to do something to make sure that all the addresses that my_malloc returns are within the heap bounds, because other parts of my application need this.

BTW, note that I do not need to lock my call to create_mspace, since I'm only using one thread in this program.  Anyway, I tried setting this argument to 1, but I saw no difference in the results.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `main` function doesn't call `my_malloc()` at all.

Comment: Just a typing error:  s/malloc/my_malloc/ (please).  Thanks.

Comment: Have corrected the posting.  The problem itself remains.

Answer (score 3):

Eureka (hahaha)!  The above, simplified example, with the given constants, will work correctly, and the returned addresses will be within range.  However, if you call my_malloc on sizes that are too large relative to the original mspace, malloc will call mmap (unless you explicitly disable this).  The addresses I was seeing were merely those returned as a result of those calls to mmap.  So the solution to this mystery turned out to be rather simple.  I'm leaving this posted in case others happen to run into this issue and forget about malloc's calls to mmap.